# Lowest-Cost Leaderboard system using firebase

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to **effectively** get a list of children (ordered* and indexed**) with the lowest number of data transfer.

* ordered: ordered by points for each user / database child

** indexed: 2 or less ranks behind/after the current user [A specific child] (further elaborated below)

My database structure is as follows:-

[image: Database Structure]

I basically want to get the first 3 users ordered by points (simple):-

```kotlin
val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DB_LINK).getReference("users").orderByChild("points")
usersRef.limitToFirst(3).addValueEventListener(
    object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                val points: String = snapshot.child("points").getValue(String::class.java)!!
                val firstName: String = snapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String::class.java) ?: ""
                val uid: String = snapshot.key!!
                // Update View
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
    }
)
```

Then, provided that the currently logged in user isn't one of the first three, I want to get his rank (order according to points in the whole db), 2 users' before him, and 2 users' after him without querying the whole database (it's a user database that can get up to 50K unique users) because querying the whole database is a really expensive client-side task.

I checked [firebase data filtering page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) but found nothing useful about limiting results according to a certain child.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55319294/15445843) doesn't satisfy my needs, as it loops over the whole database (in my case, 50K records). I need an effective method as I need to really save these firebase bills.

Moreover, I check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64265152/15445843) but it didn't meet my needs because it still queries the whole database, meaning it is not effective and will be billed for each node before the current user. (Maybe he is number 40,000 in the db, so I shouldn't query the whole db each time to get his rank and get billed for 39,999 reads)

I searched for a way to somehow use booleans to filter queries but again found nothing useful. Here is my not-effective code:-

```kotlin
// Gets all children.
usersRef.addValueEventListener(
    object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                val points: String = snapshot.child("points").getValue(String::class.java)!!
                val firstName: String = snapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String::class.java) ?: ""
                val uid: String = snapshot.key!!
                // Update View only if user is `2 <= usersRank - theirRank <= -2`
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
    }
)
```

I want to achieve something like this:- (Styling already done, logic remaining)

[image: Leaderboard Sample]

Is there a way to achieve this? Any alternatives?

EDIT: I found out that firestore offers [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) that may help in this situation. Doing more research to further narrow down the costs.

Comment: Creating a leaderboard where every user has a ranking is actually quite complex on a NoSQL database such as Firebase's Realtime Database. I recommend reading Dan's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720997/leaderboard-ranking-with-firebase. While it was written for Firestore, the same logic and trade-offs apply to the Realtime Database. Also see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318674/how-to-get-the-position-of-an-item-in-the-realtime-database

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the comment! For the first answer, it answered about half my question, but the second answer just loops over all the database, and that's what I really fear. (~50K records, not much money to spend)

Comment: Also, fire**store**.count() seems a great option, but I can't find [aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) for a real time database.

Comment: After doing some math calculations, applying the first answer only would limit the calls per month to 100,800,000 with 50K users (Only to get leaderboard data). I have other operations such as write (50,000) and update (Once per user per minute or something [I'll try researching how to avoid that too]). And, according to my pocket, I can't pay for that each month.

Comment: Should I take the time porting to fire-store?

Comment: Hmmm... using `COUNT()` for this is an interesting one indeed. I hadn't considered that yet.

Comment: I will try it and maybe answer my own question if it got re-opened cuz I don't find it a duplicate of that question they linked

Comment: I had posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087928/13130697) that uses COUNT queries for a leaderboard that might be useful if you decide to use Firestore for it.

Comment: Hmm.. your answer is a beneficial one. I think I can combine things up to finalize this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is not available on a Firebase Realtime Database. A better option would be Firestore.

## Why?

Well, A fire-store database can give you the count of objects in a certain query. This is a new feature added by firebase. You basically type the query you want, then add `.count()` before `.get()`; that way it'll return the count of objects only. This is called aggregation queries. Learn more about them [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation).

## Cloud Functions - Why isn't it appropriate here?

Using a Cloud Function for aggregations avoids some of the issues with client-side transactions, but comes with a different set of limitations:

- Cost - Each rating added will cause a Cloud Function invocation, which may increase your costs. For more information, see the Cloud Functions [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).
- Latency - By offloading the aggregation work to a Cloud Function, your app will not see updated data until the Cloud Function has finished executing and the client has been notified of the new data. Depending on the speed of your Cloud Function, this could take longer than executing the transaction locally.
- Write rates - this solution may not work for frequently updated aggregations because Cloud Firestore documents can only be updated at most once per second. Additionally, If a transaction reads a document that was modified outside of the transaction, it retries a finite number of times and then fails.

## Combining this with other methods

Now that you're using `COUNT()` for this system, there is one more method to help further narrow down the costs. That is Periodic Updates.

## Periodic Updates

Who would care about a live ranking of all users? You can make the leaderboard update each minute, hour, or day. For example, stack overflow's leaderboard is updated once a day!

This approach would really work for any number of players and any write rate. However, you might need to adjust the frequency though as you grow depending on your willingness to pay.

## Costs Side

For each normal read, you are charged for one read. Very simple. However, for one count, you're charged for 0.001 reads (meaning 1000 counts = 1 read). For more information about costs, check [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) by firebase.

## Final Thoughts

To connect everything up, we shall now apply this on our problem. Firstly, we'll need to keep the first portion of the code as it is. (The portion that grabs the first 3 users), though with some changes to port it to firebase.

NOTICE: Don't forget to setup a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes) because we're ordering by multiple fields at the same time.

```kotlin
val top3 = HashMap<Int, HashMap<String, String>>()

Firebase.firestore.collection("users").orderBy("points", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .orderBy("firstName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .get().addOnSuccessListener {
    for ((index, doc) in it.documents.withIndex()) {
        val firstName = doc.getString("firstName")!!
        val points = doc.getString("points")!!
        top3[index+1] = hashMapOf("first" to firstName, "points" to points, "uid" to doc.id)
    }
}
```

- More about ordering and limiting [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Then, we'll need to implement the `COUNT()` feature.

```kotlin
Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    .whereGreaterThan("points", UserProfile.getInstance()!!.getProfile().points)
    .count().get(AggregateSource.SERVER).addOnSuccessListener {
    println("Your rank is: ${it.count+1}")
}
```

Basically what I did here was:-

1. Selecting the Collection
2. Ordered Ascending by first name so no duplicate ranks.
3. Count them, and pass onto the function.

The final step is just updating the hash map `top3` and rank of user each hour/day/minute/...